# How to click HTML button programatically by vb.net

Tags: vb.net

I am trying to click a button programatically . The button is on the 3rd page of the website. and it does not have any id . It has just name , type and value . The HTML code of the button is given below

```
<FORM NAME='form1' METHOD='post' action='/dflogin.php'>
<INPUT TYPE='hidden' NAME='txtId' value='E712050-15'>
<INPUT TYPE='hidden'NAME='txtassId' value='1'>
<INPUT TYPE='hidden' NAME='txtPsw' value='HH29'>
<INPUT TYPE='hidden' NAME='txtLog' value='0'>
 <h6 align='right'>
 <INPUT TYPE='SUBMIT' NAME='btnSub' value='Next' style='background-color:#009900;    color:#fff;'></h6></FORM>
```

I have tried these codes in vb.net 2008 express edition...

```
For Each webpageelement As HtmlElement In allelements

            If webpageelement.GetAttribute("value") = "Next" Then

                webpageelement.InvokeMember("click")

            End If
        Next
```

And 2nd one

```
theElementCollection = WebBrowser1.Document.GetElementsByTagName("INPUT")

    For Each curElement As HtmlElement In theElementCollection

        ctrlIdentity = curElement.GetAttribute("innerText").ToString

        If ctrlIdentity = "Next" Then

            curElement.InvokeMember("click")

        End If

    Next
```

and 3rd one is

```
      Dim l_forms = WebBrowser1.Document.GetElementsByTagName("form")
        If l_forms.Count > 0 Then
            l_forms.Item(0).InvokeMember("submit")
        End If
and 4th one is

Do While WebBrowser1.ReadyState <> WebBrowserReadyState.Complete
Application.DoEvents()
Loop
WebBrowser1.Document.Body.InnerHtml = Replace(WebBrowser1.Document.Body.InnerHtml,"NAME='btnSub'", "NAME='btnSub' id='btnSub'") 'insert id into youre button
WebBrowser1.Document.GetElementById("btnSub").InvokeMember("click") 'click on btnSub
```

and the last one is

```
Dim i As Integer
        Dim allButtons As HtmlElementCollection

        allButtons = WebBrowser1.Document.GetElementsByTagName("input")

        i = 0
        For Each webpageelement As HtmlElement In allButtons
            i += 1
            If i = 5 Then
                webpageelement.InvokeMember("click")
            End If
        Next
```

These all codes are unable to click that button. Kindly Please Suggest a appropriate solution for clicking this button. Thank You So Much

Comment: why not just use javascript from code behind

Answer (score 0):

something like this would be a server side JavaScript and jquery solution

```
string script = "$(document).ready(function() {$('input[name=btnSub]').trigger('click'); });";
ScriptManager.RegisterStartupScript(this, GetType(), "ServerControlScript", script, true);
```

Comment: can u pleasse write the complete coding